# filter function using match with regex

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get all the buttons that have id check-button_n being n in range 0 to 20 and perform click on them.

I used the following code for this:

```
$('button').filter(function () {this.id.match(/^check-button_/)}).click();
```

However it is not working. the match always returns null even though the id returns check-button_0, check-button_1, etc.
Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?
Alternatively, can anyone tell me how to extract all buttons wit the matching id as explained before and perform click on them?

In tpl:

Check
            
          
Thanks!

I am new in javascript and jquery so detailed explanations would be appreciated! :)

Comment: regex is correct seems working here https://regexr.com/3hac4

Comment: Thanks Kalpesh but that is not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However it is not working. the match always returns null even though
>   the id returns check-button_0, check-button_1, etc.

You need to **return** the matches in the `filter`'s callback

```
$('button').filter(function () { return this.id.match(/^check-button_/)});
```

Or simply use the *attribute starts-with selector* `^=`

```
$('button[id^="check-button_"]');
```

> Alternatively, can anyone tell me how to extract all buttons wit the
>   matching id as explained before and perform click on them?

```
$('button[id^="check-button_"]').each( function(){
   var id = +this.id.substring( "check-button_".length ); //13 is the length of `check-button_`
   if ( id >= 0 && id <= 20 )
   {
      $(this).click();
   }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! the filter is working now but the click isn't working for the first button in IE (for the rest of buttons it is fine). In chrome and firefox working fine also the first one... please help

Comment: @user3683638 It is difficult to tell without seeing rest of code, can you share a working snippet or a fiddle?

Comment: @HassanImam No, match will return null if there is no match

Comment: Thanks @gurvinder372, got confuse there for a moment.

Comment: @ gurvinder372 - my mistake. I wanted to say click on the filtered buttons is not working at all. Probably I am doing it wrong.. I tried: 
$('button').filter(function () { return this.id.match(/^check-button_/)}).click();